# Do I need a menorah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

It's been common practice for a very long time (perhaps as early as [60 years after the Chanukah miracle](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45122/5323)) to use a [menorah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menorah_(Hanukkah)) (aka "[chanukiyah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22693/5323)") to light the Chanukah candles with.

**Do I need a menorah to light Chanukah candles?** Or can I just plop my candles or oil cups down on the table, and light them there?

Comment: This question came partly from starting to ask a different question, and partly because I heard a story about the Rav, who used to commute to YU from Boston, and would occasionally forget his menorah. When that happened, he would melt some candles into the windowsill of his apartment, and light them there. .....apparently, he held that you do *not* need a *kli* for Chanukah lights.

Comment: ....anyhow, I've [asked and answered my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but I'd love to get more answers, particularly those with a better look at the issue than the one I provided.

Comment: There is a difference in using candles and oil

Comment: @sam yeah....I can't just drop my oil on the table without a cup to hold it :P ....but more seriously, thanks for that info! Where might I find more information about that?

Comment: I meant candles don't need a menorah but oil does

Comment: @sam I figured as much :) ....do you have any nice sources I can look up about that?

Comment: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/823353/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Is_a_Menorah_Necessary_for_Ner_Chanukah

Comment: Shoket, the story you mention is quoted in the shiur that I linked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Avnei Nezer 2:500 quotes several opinions that state that one needs to have the candles lit in some sort of kli (vessel) and not just stuck onto a table. ([h/t: DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22603/5323)) R. Shmuel Kamenetsky (Kovetz Hil. Chanukah pg. 29) also writes that one should be careful to use a kli, even if one is using wax candles that can stand by themselves.

However, R. Hershel Schachter (Nefesh Harav pg. 226) quotes that R. J.B. Soloveitchik would make fun of those who were *machmir* regarding this issue, saying that there's no reason to require a kli.

For further discussion: http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/823353/Rabbi_Aryeh_Lebowitz/Is_a_Menorah_Necessary_for_Ner_Chanukah

Comment: Can't we quote the ramma and mishna berurah who discuss putting candles on the wall or on the table too?

Comment: @Matt In the case of R' Shmuel Kamenetsky, would he then argue against lighting candles and saying the brachot if one does not have a kli? I mean, if one is unfortunate enough not to have a menorah or kli of any time, would it be considered a wasted bracha to try to do the mitzvah with just candles?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you do need a menorah, according to some opinions brought by the *Avnei Nezer* (2:500), cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22603/5323) by Double AA.

( *I found this answer while doing research for this question* :P )