# Do you need to use the same chanukia for all eight nights of Chanukah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

The answers to [Do I need a menorah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50708/do-i-need-a-menorah) say that according to some I need to use a *chanukia* of some sort to hold the lights.  Does it need to be the same one for all eight days, or can one use different *chanukiot* on different nights of the festival?

Comment: edited to remove the need for a psak halocho.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If this question is turned into whether a chanukiya is required at all, it becomes at least a partial duplicate: that question is [already answered on the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50708/do-i-need-a-menorah)

Comment: Shlomo, I've edited further to make this question not a duplicate of the one Rish linked to.  I think this is still pretty close to what you intended to ask all along.  If not, please feel free to [edit] further.

Answer (score 5):

See [Shulchan Aruch 673:3](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%92_%D7%92) who is very clear that you can use different Menorahs each night (he says that if you are lighting with earthenware you have to use new ones each night).

Comment: The question was "if a hannukiah is needed". Does the Shulhan Arukh hold that one needs one?