# Can one light a "camp fire" for Chanukah lighting?

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia

This [M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50711/5275) discusses a controversy as to whether one needs a vessel for Chanukah lighting.

Based on the opinion that one doesn't need a vessel, could one make a camp fire (i.e. a pile of twigs and just lit the pile) and use that for candle lighting? What if after the first night, one had a large field and had separate camp fires but from a distance, they were noticeable as being in a straight line?

For the opinion that says that one needs a vessel, if you surround the twigs with a small wall of rocks (say about 2-3 feet high), would that suffice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The halacha is that someone must light with a *ner* (individual wick) and not a *medurah* (torch or multiple wicks). Siman תרעא in the *Shulchan Aruch* explains that the wicks must be separated to show individually even if all the individual wicks lead back to a central source. A camp fire is like the situation in which multiple wicks are lit, but the individual wicks are not separated by a kli.

Siman Katan ד

> מילה קערה שמן והקיפה פסילות אם כפה עליה כלי כל פסילה עולה בשביל נר אחד
>   לא כפה עליה כלי אפילו לנר אחד אינו עולה לפי שהוא כמדורה
>
> If one fills a plate with oil and put wicks in it, if he covers it
>   with a utensil he fulfills the mitzvah since each wick rises as a
>   single *ner*. If he does not cover it, even if he treats them all as a
>   single *ner*, he does not fulfill the mitzvah because it is like a
>   *medurah* (torch).