# How do I light the other candles with the shamash if I use wick and oil rather than candles?

Tags: chanuka

I'd like to change over from candles to wick and oil for lighting my Chanukah candles, but I can't figure out how you light the other candles from a wick and oil shamash. Todah.

Comment: B. Austin, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks for bringing your question here! Fortunately, we have answers all ready for you, and your new phrasing of this question will help internet searchers who have the same question and think about it in similar terms to yours, so thanks! I hope you'll stick around and keep asking and answering. PS: You might find this useful too: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15/whats-the-best-way-to-make-wick-and-oil-work-for-chanukah

Comment: Hi B, can I also recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?